# Fast way to retrieve information from huge csv file in python by column and row name

Tags: python, pandas, tabular

I am trying to find a fast and memory-efficient way to retrieve specific data points from a tabular file that looks similar to this:

```
chrom:pos   04a0    7ee8    88ca    477a
chr1:925745 3   1   5   1
chr1:925746 3   1   5   1
chr1:925747 4   1   8   1
chr1:925749 4   1   5   1
```

In this table the row names as well as the column names are unique. The original file has a size of 7GB. It does not change, thus I could also convert it into a different format, if this speeds up the process.
Maybe there is a way to generate an index beforehand?

I would like to be able to retrieve the integer `8` by just specifying the name of the column and row I'm interested in, e.g. using a function `func("chr1:925747", "88ca")`.

So far, I have tried using `pandas` on a subset of my huge file (just 330 MB) and it takes >30 seconds to retrieve the information, which is way too slow for my use case.

My pandas code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys

inputfile = sys.argv[1]
chrompos = sys.argv[2]
id = sys.argv[3]


data=pd.read_csv(inputfile, sep="\t", index_col=0)
result=data.at[chrompos, id]
print result
```

Would maybe using an sql table help..? I generated a sql table from the pandas dataframe using "`.to_sql`", but then my column headers are lost.

Comment: what do you mean your headers are lost? what do they become?

Comment: just throw your data in a database as you mentioned and a simple select along with a where clause will give you the results significantly faster

Comment: @Nullman when I convert with `.to_sql`, and then run `engine.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table").fetchall()`, I'll only get `[(u'chr1:925745', 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3,...`

Comment: Have you timed this 30s from the start or from when it does the data.at?  If you are doing several retrievals, they should only be timed from the data.at.  Reading 7Gb of data using this method will not work

Comment: @aws_apprentice maybe you are right, and I should give this a try. I was too much into my python solution to think about generating a database first and testing how fast this is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use datatable which is faster reading data than the pandas but there not all functionality in datatable that available in pandas

```
import datatable as dt
dt_df = dt.fread("../input/loan.csv")
```

but after reading you can convert it into pandas

```
   dt_df.to_pandas()
```